# how to make a code which can write tables of given n numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

[![IDE screenshot][1]][1]

i need the code which extend itself as we provide more inputs and like i have a b=2 x 2 but I also want to give space and print 3 x 2 in front of b like (2 x 2=4    3 x 2=6) this and if i need to add 4 also in front of 3 my code should change itself and add one more variable in print so i can get 4 x 2=8 in front of (2 x 2=4    3 x 2=6)this after one tab.

````py
# python version used is 3.8.5 
a=[2,3,4,5]
n=len(a)
if n==0:
    print("please give input")
if n==1:
    for a in a:
        for i in range(10):
            i+=1
            form = f"{a} X {i} = {a*i}"
            print(f"{form}")

elif n==2:
    for i in range(10):
        i+=1
        form0 = f"{a[0]} X {i} = {a[0]*i}"
        form1 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        print(f"{form0}\t {form1}")

elif n==3:
    for i in range(10):
        i+=1
        form0 = f"{a[0]} X {i} = {a[0]*i}"
        form1 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form2 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        print(f"{form0}\t {form1}\t {form2}")

elif n==4:
    for i in range(10):
        i+=1
        form0 = f"{a[0]} X {i} = {a[0]*i}"
        form1 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form2 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form3 = f"{a[3]} X {i} = {a[3]*i}"
        print(f"{form0}\t {form1}\t {form2}\t {form3}")

elif n==5:
    for i in range(10):
        i+=1
        form0 = f"{a[0]} X {i} = {a[0]*i}"
        form1 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form2 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form3 = f"{a[3]} X {i} = {a[3]*i}"
        form4 = f"{a[4]} X {i} = {a[4]*i}"
        print(f"{form0}\t {form1}\t {form2}\t {form3}\t {form4}")

elif n==6:
    for i in range(10):
        i+=1
        form0 = f"{a[0]} X {i} = {a[0]*i}"
        form1 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form2 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form3 = f"{a[3]} X {i} = {a[3]*i}"
        form4 = f"{a[4]} X {i} = {a[4]*i}"
        form5 = f"{a[5]} X {i} = {a[5]*i}"
        print(f"{form0}\t {form1}\t {form2}\t {form3}\t {form4}\t {form5}")
elif n==7:
    for i in range(10):
        i+=1
        form0 = f"{a[0]} X {i} = {a[0]*i}"
        form1 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form2 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form3 = f"{a[3]} X {i} = {a[3]*i}"
        form4 = f"{a[3]} X {i} = {a[3]*i}"
        form5 = f"{a[5]} X {i} = {a[5]*i}"
        form6 = f"{a[6]} X {i} = {a[6]*i}"
        print(f"{form0}\t {form1}\t {form2}\t {form3}\t {form4}\t {form5}\t {form6}")

elif n==8:
    for i in range(10):
        i+=1
        form0 = f"{a[0]} X {i} = {a[0]*i}"
        form1 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form2 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form3 = f"{a[3]} X {i} = {a[3]*i}"
        form4 = f"{a[3]} X {i} = {a[3]*i}"
        form5 = f"{a[5]} X {i} = {a[5]*i}"
        form6 = f"{a[6]} X {i} = {a[6]*i}"
        form7 = f"{a[7]} X {i} = {a[7]*i}"
        print(f"{form0}\t {form1}\t {form2}\t {form3}\t {form4}\t {form5}\t {form6}\t {form7}")

elif n==9:
    for i in range(10):
        i+=1
        form0 = f"{a[0]} X {i} = {a[0]*i}"
        form1 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form2 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form3 = f"{a[3]} X {i} = {a[3]*i}"
        form4 = f"{a[3]} X {i} = {a[3]*i}"
        form5 = f"{a[5]} X {i} = {a[5]*i}"
        form6 = f"{a[6]} X {i} = {a[6]*i}"
        form7 = f"{a[7]} X {i} = {a[7]*i}"
        form8 = f"{a[8]} X {i} = {a[8]*i}"
        print(f"{form0}\t {form1}\t {form2}\t {form3}\t {form4}\t {form5}\t {form6}\t {form7}\t {form8}")

else:
    for i in range(10):
        i+=1
        form0 = f"{a[0]} X {i} = {a[0]*i}"
        form1 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form2 = f"{a[2]} X {i} = {a[2]*i}"
        form3 = f"{a[3]} X {i} = {a[3]*i}"
        form4 = f"{a[3]} X {i} = {a[3]*i}"
        form5 = f"{a[5]} X {i} = {a[5]*i}"
        form6 = f"{a[6]} X {i} = {a[6]*i}"
        form7 = f"{a[7]} X {i} = {a[7]*i}"
        form8 = f"{a[8]} X {i} = {a[8]*i}"
        print(f"{form0}\t {form1}\t {form2}\t {form3}\t {form4}\t {form5}\t {form6}\t {form7}\t {form8}")
        print("Space is full") ```


Any help would be greatly appreciated


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziEtc.png
````

Comment: I'm sorry, but could your rephrase your question? I'm not really sure, what the goal is. Maybe provide (one or better more) sample inputs with respective expected outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm following your logic correctly, you want to generate a multiplication table (1-10) for each number in the list (2,3,4,5):

A nested loop should do the trick:

```
a=[2,3,4,5]  # could also use [x for x in range(2,6)]

n=len(a)
if n==0:
    print("please give input")
    exit()

for i in range(10):  # 0-9
   for x in a:  # each number in list
      print(f"{x} X {i+1} = {x*(i+1)}", end="\t")  # append to row
   print()  # go to next row
```

Output

```
2 X 1 = 2       3 X 1 = 3       4 X 1 = 4       5 X 1 = 5
2 X 2 = 4       3 X 2 = 6       4 X 2 = 8       5 X 2 = 10
2 X 3 = 6       3 X 3 = 9       4 X 3 = 12      5 X 3 = 15
2 X 4 = 8       3 X 4 = 12      4 X 4 = 16      5 X 4 = 20
2 X 5 = 10      3 X 5 = 15      4 X 5 = 20      5 X 5 = 25
2 X 6 = 12      3 X 6 = 18      4 X 6 = 24      5 X 6 = 30
2 X 7 = 14      3 X 7 = 21      4 X 7 = 28      5 X 7 = 35
2 X 8 = 16      3 X 8 = 24      4 X 8 = 32      5 X 8 = 40
2 X 9 = 18      3 X 9 = 27      4 X 9 = 36      5 X 9 = 45
2 X 10 = 20     3 X 10 = 30     4 X 10 = 40     5 X 10 = 50
```

Comment: Thank you very. i am looking this code from self replicating code type.i am beginner so i don't know this variation of print(). Thanks again.

Comment: Please accept an answer so this post is removed from the "No Answer" list. Thanks.